# cканирование qr-code в django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Сейчас я работаю над проектом, который может сканировать QR-код, содержащий идентификатор товара. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ включить на моем веб-сайте камеру iPhone для сканирования и как вообще можно сканировать и открыть ссылку на web site? Пожалуйста, дайте мне информацию об этом или ссылку.

Comment: ищите библиотеки на js по сканированию и распознаванию кодов

Comment: я очень много искал но правда я нашел для android а для сайта я не нашел у вас есть ссылка ?

Comment: Чем вам не подходит эта ссылка? https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20qr%20code%20scanner